# Como modificar un atributo especifico dentro de un archivo txt java

Tags: java

¿Como están?.

Mi duda surge porque tengo un archivo .txt que guarda datos de unos artículos (ID, nombre, precio, etc).
Tengo que lograr la forma de modificar el atributo que yo desee en el archivo y luego volver a mostrarlo por pantalla. Suponiendo que tengo

```
private String nameAr;
private int codeAr;
private int precioAr;
private int cantStock;
private int idAr;
```

¿Con que método yo podría modificar, por ejemplo, el precio del articulo X en mi fichero, guardarlo y volver a mostrarlo en pantalla modificado?

por ejemplo:
en mi txt tengo
ID: 1
Producto: Heladera
Cod: 3000
Precio:$ 30
Stock disponible: 10

ID: 2
Producto: Teclado
Cod: 3030
Precio:$ 120
Stock disponible: 100

y quiero seleccionar al articulo 2 para modificar su Precio, como podría hacer? Muchas gracias.

Comment: sugiero que cambies el formato de tu archivo txt a un formato json o xml que te facilitaría la lectura y escritura, además en la comprensión de la información que tienes. Bajo el esquema que tienes se puede realizar pero queda abierto a muchos errores además de que mientras más artículos tengas más líneas leerás y re procesaras para recuperar, guardar y actualizar información.

Comment: Como podria cambiarlo?

Comment: Estoy suponiendo por tu enunciado que tu eres el que crea y mantiene el archivo de productos por medio de tu programa java. Un archivo XML lo puedes generar con jdom, si es un archivo json el que quieres usa gson. en ambos casos vas a obtener un string, ese string solo guárdalo en tu archivo productos, sigue siendo texto, solo que con un formato muy especifico para el manejo de información. ahora tu archivo contendrá información mejor estructurada que es mucho más fácil de analizar y procesar para tu programa java.

Comment: es posible guardar los objetos en un arraylist, y este arraylist guardarlo en un xml para luego poder modificarlo? creo que es esa la solucion pero no logro hacerlo

Comment: No puedes, ni con json, ni con fichero de texto con el formato que te llegues a inventar. Un fichero es una secuencia de datos en disco en el que puedes añadir datos al final, pero no puedes modificar en la mitad. Tendrás que leer todo el fichero, modificar en memoria los datos que quieras y volver a escribir todo el fichero. Lo hagas con json y una clase que suba a memoria pareseado el fichero, o como quieras. Cuando quieras reescribir el fichero se reescribirá entero.

Comment: DamianCoronel exacto, manejarías tus datos en un ArrayList de objetos obtenidos de tu archivo plano (luego de la lectura), y como indica @SuperG280, no es que vas a ir a la linea 50 y modificar el registro de id 105, si no que volverás a escribir el archivo con el mismo jdom o gson que te devuelve el texto en xml o json respectivamente y reescribir el archivo con el ArrayList que ya haz "tratado" - "modificado"

Answer (score 0):

Hola en primer lugar no lo deberías guardar como txt ó texto plano (aunque puedes usar esa extensión si gustas, pero se va a ver codificado).
La solución a tú planteamiento es la siguiente:
1ero. Debes crear una clase que vá a contener todos tus datos.
2do. Dicha clase debe implementar la interface Serializable, adicionalmente te recomendaría definir todos los getters y setters, también la función toString y todos los equals() and hashCode().

para tú ejemplo, la clase quedaría así:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Data implements Serializable {

private String nameAr;
private int codeAr;
private int precioAr;
private int cantStock;
private int idAr;

public Data(String nameAr, int codeAr, int precioAr, int cantStock, int idAr) {
    this.nameAr = nameAr;
    this.codeAr = codeAr;
    this.precioAr = precioAr;
    this.cantStock = cantStock;
    this.idAr = idAr;
}

public String getNameAr() {
    return nameAr;
}

public void setNameAr(String nameAr) {
    this.nameAr = nameAr;
}

public int getCodeAr() {
    return codeAr;
}

public void setCodeAr(int codeAr) {
    this.codeAr = codeAr;
}

public int getPrecioAr() {
    return precioAr;
}

public void setPrecioAr(int precioAr) {
    this.precioAr = precioAr;
}

public int getCantStock() {
    return cantStock;
}

public void setCantStock(int cantStock) {
    this.cantStock = cantStock;
}

public int getIdAr() {
    return idAr;
}

public void setIdAr(int idAr) {
    this.idAr = idAr;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.nameAr);
    hash = 37 * hash + this.codeAr;
    hash = 37 * hash + this.precioAr;
    hash = 37 * hash + this.cantStock;
    hash = 37 * hash + this.idAr;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Data other = (Data) obj;
    if (this.codeAr != other.codeAr) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.precioAr != other.precioAr) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.cantStock != other.cantStock) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.idAr != other.idAr) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(this.nameAr, other.nameAr);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Data{");
    sb.append("nameAr=").append(nameAr);
    sb.append(", codeAr=").append(codeAr);
    sb.append(", precioAr=").append(precioAr);
    sb.append(", cantStock=").append(cantStock);
    sb.append(", idAr=").append(idAr);
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
}  
}
```

Ahora necesitas crear otra clase que tiene los métodos para: guardarObjeto, leerObjeto, y otros más ;) te paso el código aquí mismo:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class ManejoArchivos {

public static void guardarObjeto(String pathName, Object objeto) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream archivo = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathName));
    archivo.writeObject(objeto);
    archivo.close();
}

public static Object leerObjeto(String pathName) {

    File archivo = new File(pathName);

    if (!archivo.exists()) {
        System.out.println("El archivo no existe!");
    } else {
        try {

            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathName));
            Object objeto = entrada.readObject();
            entrada.close();
            return objeto;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ManejoArchivos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ManejoArchivos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ManejoArchivos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean existeArchivo(String pathName) {
    File archivo = new File(pathName);
    return archivo.exists();
}

public static void eliminarArchivo(String pathName) {
    File archivo = new File(pathName);
    System.out.println(archivo.exists());// regresa true o false dependiendo si existe o no el archivo
    archivo.delete();
    System.out.println("Se eliminó el archivo");
}

}
```

Ahora necesitas una tercera clase, que es la que va a contener el método main y vas a poder hacer eso, que tanto quieres:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.*;
import static tests.ManejoArchivos.*;


public class TestArchivo {

private final String PATH_DATA_FILE = "archivo.dat";

public TestArchivo() {
    
    Data data = new Data("Pelota", 12, 100, 25, 5555);
    try {
        guardarObjeto(PATH_DATA_FILE, data);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestArchivo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
    Data dataRecuperada = (Data) leerObjeto(PATH_DATA_FILE);
    
    System.out.println(dataRecuperada);
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestArchivo();
}
}
```

Ahora sí, listo!!! espero puedas resolver tú y otras personas más.